# Erro com Bootstrap (Font Awesome)

Tags: font-awesome

Estou usando Bootstrap e tentando adicionar o ícone "like", porem aparece esse quadrado no lugar... qual o problema?

```html
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--codigo usado para adicionar o simbologo like-->
<button class = "btn btn-primary"><i class = "fa fa-thumbs-up">
</i>Submit</button>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem esse font-awesome.min.css na pasta do css?

Comment: sim, eu baixei e coloquei na pasta do css

Comment: Bom tentei aqui com o esse link <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> e funcionou, testa com ele no seu, se não funcionar tenta remover essas 2 class só para ver aqui ele olha https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZWMZB